# How to drop X number of rows using where condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have a dataset from which I want to drop *only* 1165 rows where the sentiment value is equal to 2 (in total there are 1465 rows where sentiment is equal to 2).

I searched on Stackoverflow and the solutions I am getting end up dropping all the rows where the sentiment value = 2 which is not what i want to do.

I used the following code but it does not work:

```
updated_data_reviews  = data_reviews.loc(data_reviews[data_reviews["Sentiment"] == 2 ].index[:1165])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it matter which of the rows are dropped? If so, which ones should be dropped? And *why do you want to keep* the others? And *what is the rule that tells you* how many to drop?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select rows instead of dropping them, here is how you could do it:

```
indices_to_drop = data_reviews[data_reviews["Sentiment"] == 2].index[:1165]

updated_data_reviews = data_reviews.drop(indices_to_drop)
```